# What's the time complexity of this parentheses combination?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Implement an algorithm to print all valid (aka. properly opened and closed) combinations of n pairs of parentheses.
*(BTW, this is a question from the book `<Cracking coding interview>` chp 8, question 8.9)*

Here is the solution:

**ParenthesesCombination.java**:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParenthesesCombination {
    /**
     * Find all combinations with n pairs.
     *
     * @param n
     * @return
     */
    public static List<String> getAll(int n) {
        if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("n should >= 1, but get: " + n);
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

        getAll(n, n, 0, new char[n * 2], list);

        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Find cases with given buffer & index.
     *
     * @param leftRemaining  left remain count,
     * @param rightRemaining right remain count,
     * @param curIdx         current index in buffer,
     * @param buf            buffer,
     * @param list           result list,
     */
    protected static void getAll(int leftRemaining, int rightRemaining, int curIdx, char[] buf, List<String> list) {
        if (leftRemaining < 0 || rightRemaining < leftRemaining) return; // invalid, discard it,
        if (leftRemaining == 0 && rightRemaining == 0) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(buf)); // found, make a copy, and add,
            return;
        }

        // try to add '(',
        buf[curIdx] = '(';
        getAll(leftRemaining - 1, rightRemaining, curIdx + 1, buf, list);

        // try to add ')',
        buf[curIdx] = ')';
        getAll(leftRemaining, rightRemaining - 1, curIdx + 1, buf, list);
    }
}
```

Sample combination:

```
pair count: 4, combination count: 14
     0: (((())))
     1: ((()()))
     2: ((())())
     3: ((()))()
     4: (()(()))
     5: (()()())
     6: (()())()
     7: (())(())
     8: (())()()
     9: ()((()))
    10: ()(()())
    11: ()(())()
    12: ()()(())
    13: ()()()()
```

The sample pair count and combination count are:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 5
4 -> 14
5 -> 42
6 -> 132
7 -> 429
```

According to the algorithm it should be between:

`O(2^n)` and `O(4^n)`

But, is there a way to get a more accurate time complexity?

Comment: does it say the parentheses must have something inside them?

Comment: @Sirmyself I added a sample output.

Comment: oh I see, I though that you were making an algorithm to validate parentheses in a string of some sort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precise number of output lines is equal to the Catalan numbers: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number. The nth Catalan number is Theta(4^n/n^(3/2)), so the running time is Theta(4^n/√n).

Comment: Note that this is true only if the algorithm is optimally efficient (i.e., its search space is comparable to the output solution), which the algorithm as written above actually is, at most only double the number of operation compared to actual Catalan number.

Comment: You included the factor of n required to copy/print the output :)  +1